# combining a list of dictionaries with another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with a set amount of dictionaries inside which I have to compare to one other dictionary.

They have the following form (there is no specific form or pattern for keys and values, these are randomly chosen examples):

```
list1 = [
    {'X1': 'Q587', 'X2': 'Q67G7', ...},
    {'AB1': 'P5K7', 'CB2': 'P678', ...},
    {'B1': 'P6H78', 'C2': 'BAA5', ...}]

dict1 = {
    'X1': set([B00001,B00020,B00010]),
    'AB1': set([B00001,B00007,B00003]), 
    'C2': set([B00001,B00002,B00003]),  ...
}
```

What I want to have now is a new dictionary which has as keys: the values of the dictionaries in list1. and as values the values of dict1. And this only when the keys intersect in compared dictionaries.

I have done this in the following way:

```
nDicts = len(list1)
resultDict = {}

    for key in range(0,nDicts):
            for x in list1[key].keys():
                if x in dict1.keys():
                    resultDict.update{list1[key][x]:dict1[x]}
                    print resultDict
```

The desired output should be of the form:

```
resulDict = {
        'Q587': set([B00001,B00020,B00010]),
        'P5K7': set([B00001,B00007,B00003]), 
        'BAA5': set([B00001,B00002,B00003]),  ...
    }
```

This works but since the amount of data is so high this takes forever.
Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I have changed the input values a little, the only ones that matter are the keys which intersect between the dictionaries within list1 and those within dict1.

Comment: Which one is larger? `list1` or `dict1`?

Comment: Are there keys which appear in more than one dictionary within `list1`?

Comment: Can you please show some actual sample data (that can be evaluated and used, not syntax errors) and the desired output for it?

Comment: Your code sample produces a dictionary **per shared key**, but your question seems to expect to produce *one* dictionary holding all shared keys instead. Can you clarify?

Comment: - list1 is larger (approx. 3 dicts with 200k entries in the example)
- the keys for the combined dictionaries in list1 are all unique
- I do need one dictionary for all shared keys so I should append presumably?

Comment: small follow up question: I removed the print statement in the loop and wrote everything to a file which seemed to increase the speed greatly. At first it was just printing endlessly, what exactly is the cause of that?

Comment: @paul_dg: Well, you had a `print` statement inside the inner loop, so it was printing one dict for each key in each of your 600k entries, which is going to seem endless. I don't know how many keys each dict has, or how many lines each result dict takes to print, but we're talking millions of lines minimum, which will certainly _seem_ endless. And if you're letting output go to the terminal, some terminals (especially Windows' default cmd.exe) could take much longer to display all that output than your actual processing takes.

Comment: @abarnet You are right, a very simple mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keys` method in Python 2.x makes a list with a copy of all of the keys, and you're doing this not only for each dict in `list1` (probably not a big deal, but it's hard to know for sure without knowing your data), but also doing it for `dict1` over and over again.

On top of that, doing an `in` test on a list takes a long time, because it has to check each value in the list until it finds a match, but doing an `in` test on a dictionary is nearly instant, because it just has to look up the hash value.

Both `keys` are actually completely unnecessary—iterating a dict gives you the keys in order (an unspecified order, but the same is true for calling `keys()`), and `in`-checking a dict searches the same keys you'd get with `keys()`. So, just removing them does the same thing, but simpler, faster, and with less memory used. So:

```
for key in range(0,nDicts):
    for x in list1[key]:
        if x in dict1:
            resultDict={list1[key][x]:dict1[x]}
            print resultDict
```

There are also ways you can simplify this that probably won't help performance that much, but are still worth doing.

You can iterate directly over `list1` instead of building a huge list of all the indices and iterating that.

```
for list1_dict in list1:
    for x in list1_dict:
        if x in dict1:
            resultDict = {list_dict[x]: dict1[x]}
            print resultDict
```

And you can get the keys and values in a single step:

```
for list1_dict in list1:
    for k, v in list1_dict.iteritems():
        if k in dict1:
            resultDict = {v: dict1[k]}
            print resultDict
```

Also, if you expect most of the values to be found, it will take about twice as long to first check for the value and then look it up as it would to just try to look it up and handle failure. (This is not true if most of the values will *not* be found, however.) So:

```
for list1_dict in list1:
    for k, v in list1_dict.iteritems():
        try:
            resultDict = {v: dict1[k]}
            print resultDict
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: "iterating a dict gives you the keys in order". Which order?

Comment: This does what the OP's code sample does, but better. But it does not do what his question seemed to ask for, which is create a single dictionary.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: An unspecified order, but the same order that `keys()` would have given you—and it doesn't matter in this case. I've edited it to clarify the point.

Comment: @Bepetersn: The OP says that his code "works but since the amount of data is so high this takes forever". And I assume that by "works" he means it does what he actually wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and optimize your operation with set intersections; as of Python 2.7 dictionaries can represent keys as sets using the `dict.viewkeys()` method, or `dict.keys()` in Python 3:

```
resultDict = {}

for d in list1:
    for sharedkey in d.viewkeys() & dict1:
        resultDict[d[sharedkey]] = dict1[sharedkey]
```

This can be turned into a dict comprehension even:

```
resultDict = {d[sharedkey]: dict1[sharedkey] 
              for d in list1 for sharedkey in d.viewkeys() & dict1}
```

I am assuming here you wanted **one** resulting dictionary, not a new dictionary per shared key.

Demo on your sample input:

```
>>> list1 = [
...     {'X1': 'AAA1', 'X2': 'BAA5'},
...     {'AB1': 'AAA1', 'CB2': 'BAA5'},
...     {'B1': 'AAA1', 'C2': 'BAA5'},
... ]
>>> dict1 = {
...     'X1': set(['B00001', 'B00002', 'B00003']),
...     'AB1': set(['B00001', 'B00002', 'B00003']),
... }
>>> {d[sharedkey]: dict1[sharedkey] 
...  for d in list1 for sharedkey in d.viewkeys() & dict1}
{'AAA1': set(['B00001', 'B00002', 'B00003'])}
```

Note that both `X1` *and* `AB1` are shared with dictionaries in `list1`, but in both cases, the resulting key is `AAA1`. Only one of these wins (the last match), but since both values in `dict1` are exactly the same anyway that doesn't make any odds in this case.

If you wanted separate dictionaries per dictionary in `list1`, simply move the `for d in list1:` loop out:

```
for d in list1:
    resultDict = {d[sharedkey]: dict1[sharedkey] for sharedkey in d.viewkeys() & dict1}
    if resultDict:  # can be empty
        print resultDict
```

If you really wanted one dictionary per shared key, move another loop out:

```
for d in list1:
    for sharedkey in d.viewkeys() & dict1:
        resultDict = {d[sharedkey]: dict1[sharedkey]}
        print resultDict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list1 = [

    {'X1': 'AAA1', 'X2': 'BAA5'},
    {'AB1': 'AAA1', 'CB2': 'BAA5'},
    {'B1': 'AAA1', 'C2': 'BAA5'}

    ]


dict1 = {
    'X1': set(['B00001','B00002','B00003']),
    'AB1': set(['B00001','B00002','B00003'])
}    


g = ( k.iteritems() for k in list1)
ite = ((a,b) for i in g for a,b in i if dict1.has_key(a))

d = dict(ite)            
print d
```